# PyQt View inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt

I have a view showing a table widget and I want to make children of this basic view.

Here is the BaseView

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
base_startup_path = os.path.join(cwd, r'gui\BaseView.ui')
Ui_base_startup, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(base_startup_path)


class BaseView(QtBaseClass, Ui_base_startup):

  def __init__(self, parent, device_controller):
    super(BaseView, self).__init__( parent)

    self.ui = Ui_base_startup.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.device_controller = device_controller

    # Create model
    self.table_model = TableModel(self.device_controller.device_model_list)

    # Insert table to current view
    self.table_widget = AbstractTableView(self, self.table_model)
    self.verticalLayout.insertWidget(1, self.table_widget.tableView)

    # Button connection
    self.m_test_pcb.clicked.connect(self.start_test)

  def start_test(self):
    boot_app_first = True
    self.setup_test_module()
    self.device_controller.start_connection(boot_app_first)

  def setup_test_module(self):
    self.device_controller.test_module = start_acquisition()
```

Then, I want to make a child of this that is more specific

```
class SpecificView(BaseView):

def __init__(self, parent, device_controller):
    super(SpecificView, self).__init__(parent, device_controller)

    # Specific stuff to be added        
    self.m_test_pcb.setText('Debug Device')

def setup_test_module(self):
    self.device_controller.test_module = specific_test()
```

So the BaseView is added to page 0 of a stacked widget and SpecificView is added to page 1 of the same stacked widget. When I run the application both page 0 and page 1 of the stacked widget display the same button (with different text showing) and the same table. At this point, everything works well.

When I press the button on page 0, the table of page 0 gets populated. However, when I press the button on page 1, the table of page 1 gets nothing and the table of page 0 is populated.

In c++ the inheritance would create two table_widget and two table_model and it would work, but I seem to be missing something with this Python code.

EDIT: I added the start_test functions

Comment: What does your `self.start_test` method actually do? Just wondering if that is where some references between views get mixed up

Comment: Please read the guidance on how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your edit is insufficient to diagnose the issue. Please read the link ekhumoro posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, the problem was that self.table_model was not updated in the Child instantiation because of a missing connection